# Laravel CRUD multi entities, routing

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, routes, crud

There are 3 entities:

**Categories**

**Subcategories**

**Photos**

(3 tables, 3 controllers, 3 models).

We need to implement CRUD operations for each entity. How to implement routing?

For example, to delete a subcategory, you need to make a DELETE request to:

categories / {category_id} / subcategories/{subcategory_id}

In the blade in href or in form action you need to write the following, for example:

`{{ route('subcategories.destroy', [$category->id, $subcategory->id])}`

But I don't need $category_id to delete a subcategory, just id subcategory is enough.

If then the same thing is implemented for photo, then you have to pass 3 parameters, 2 of which I do not need, but only the id of the photo.

I think I'm going some wrong way, can someone tell me how to implement routing and crud operations for categories and their subcategories?

routes/web.php:

```
// Category routes
 Route::resource('categories', 'CategoryController');
// Subcategories routes
 Route::prefix('categories/{category_id}')->group(function (){
    Route::resource('subcategories', 'SubcategoryController');
 });
```

SubcategoryController@destroy:

```
public function destroy($category_id, $subcategory_id)
    {
        $subcategory = Subcategory::findOrFail($subcategory_id);
        $subcategory->delete();
        return redirect('/categories/' . $subcategory->category_id);
    }
```

Tables:

[categories](https://i.stack.imgur.com/12JiA.png)

[subcategories](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FNAdr.png)

[photos](https://i.stack.imgur.com/99azD.png)

Comment: So if you don't need them why passing them i mean why grouping/prefixing subcategories with categories routes?

Comment: Because otherwise it would be illogical, I think. /categories/subcategories/{subcategory_id}/

Comment: Why would it be illogical though ?

Comment: Because I want to see what category I'm in when I see a list of subcategories. In the future I want to collapse /categories/1 -> /Films, for example.